# Change form properties from thread c#

Tags: c#

Hello I want to change the position of a form2 created from form1 with a thread in an other thread created in form2 with a struct

Edit:
I made an other post

There is an other problem,
How can I make Form2 stop thinking?

This is a similar code to keep it simple.
When Form1 is loaded a thread is created this thread runs a method with a infinite loop in it and at some time creates Form2 and keeps on looping the problem is that Form2 never stops thinking.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{//Form1
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread childThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loop);
        childThread.Start();
    }





    public void loop()
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                if (i == 45)
                {
                    Form2 f = new Form2();
                    f.Show();
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }        

    }
}
public partial class Form2 : Form
{//Form2
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public struct Rect
    {
        public int Left { get; set; }
        public int Top { get; set; }
        public int Right { get; set; }
        public int Bottom { get; set; }
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread childThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(method));
        childThread.Start();
    }
    public void method()
    {
        Rect move = new Rect();
        move.Left = 100;
        move.Top = 100;
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { mover(move); }));
    }
    public void mover(Rect move)
    {
        this.Left = move.Left;
        this.Top = move.Top;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is only showing the struct. Can you show the code where you create the form, and the code from which you want to move the form?

Comment: If I tried to create another post but not enough time had passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a method

```
void SetLeft(int left)
{
   this.Left = left;
}
```

That you can invoke it from any thread:

```
if (this.InvokeRequired) {
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { SetLeft(10); } );
} else {
    SetLeft(10);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this isn't the problem it looks like the event load in form2 never runs. form2 is created by a method called with a thread and this method has a infinite loop